# unaligned CSS overflow UL horizontal scroller

Tags: html, css, overflow

If you check out this fiddle you should see the problem http://jsfiddle.net/qo9czztj/

But ultimately, the images and headlines are contained within a div, and should a title be longer than one line of text, it will lower the image making it an uneven mess.

I have tried all the different positioning and display techniques, but I am not getting a perfect line.

Thank you for your help in advance

Matt

Example of coding:

```
<div class="below">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img src="f8a9086b222786c5845f60fdc22c6c2e.jpg" />
        <p>hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img src="f8a9086b222786c5845f60fdc22c6c2e.jpg" />
        <p>hello hello</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `ul div {display: inline-block; text-align: center; }`

to `ul li div {display: inline-block; text-align: center; vertical-align:top}`

Comment: Thanks. All sorted :D